# NetworkStream.ReadByte function randomly stutters, pausing all inputs for the duration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, tcpclient

#### The Problem

I am using a hokuyo uam-05lp-t301 sensor as input for a Unity application, every frame it sends data via ethernet to computer. Normally it only takes around 10-20ms to get this data into Unity using NetworkStream.ReadByte, according to the Unity profiler. Sometimes the application freezes and the profiler tells me the ReadByte function takes 2000ms or even 6000 in some cases. The application is completely unusable during this time.

It seems to happen quite randomly but more often when I actually interact with the sensor.

Screen cap of unity profiler at the frozen frame

[image: unity-screenshoot]

Here is the function that performs the byte reading:

```csharp
static string ReadLine(NetworkStream stream)
{
    if (stream.CanRead)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new();
        bool is_NL2 = false;
        bool is_NL = false;
        do
        {
            profMarker.Begin();
            char buf = (char)stream.ReadByte();
            profMarker.End();
            if (buf == '\n')
            {
                if (is_NL)
                {
                    is_NL2 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    is_NL = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                is_NL = false;
            }
            sb.Append(buf);
        } while (!is_NL2);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't understand networking enough to see why this is happening or how I can fix it.

#### What I have Tried

When I put the ReadLine function in a thread the application no longer freezes and the framerate is much higher, but the input from the sensor still stops for the 2-6 seconds. Using a thread is definitely preferable but not a solution.

I have tried adding ReceiveTimeout to the TCP Client thinking it might just skip the data for the frame if it takes too long. This mostly stops the application from freezing but the input still doesn't work for a few seconds. It also generates an error:

```
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Rethrow as IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Any advice would be helpful as this issue severely affects the usability of the application. Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Try dataavailable instead of canread

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just tried DataAvailable but it does not work, the application still freezes and now it only receives sensor data every few frames.

Comment: Thats odd behaviour. As other than frames happen quickly. The dataavailable is supposed to be just that. The code otherwise would hang here until it had data.

Comment: When using dataavailable the input feels slow and jittery like it is not updating as frequently, instead of the smooth motions it usually makes. The profiler says every 3 ish frames operate normally with ReadByte taking ~20ms and the other 1-2 frames is just 0ms. The profiler graph looks very spiky.